# Opening AdMob adView content when clicked in a webView instead of chrome application

Tags: android, android-intent, admob, android-webview, adview

I have been struggling about opening the url when AdView is clicked in a WebView instead of external browser for some time now. Is there a way to achieve this with a workaround or something? What we've been tried so far,

- Extending to the class is impossible since the AdView class is final (overriding the interfaces or methods)
- startActivity for the browser is called before the trigger of onAdOpened() method (overriding the interface)

What I've been searching after trying these solutions are to play with the android system but no solution so far. I tried to receive broadcasts which cast from startActivity method of activity for the android system but it seems no filter is working to capture them. I tried to create a browser activity but then there's the issue to remove chrome application as a browser so that it will launch my activity. So anything I'm missing? I heard that there are reflection ways so that you can override every startActivity methods of Activity or something like that but i couldn't find a good documentation to learn about that.

Comment: The AdView already uses a WebView to render.

Comment: And how would that help me? It's a final class so modifications are impossible in common ways

Comment: You ask how to open AdView content in a WebView instead of a chrome application. I was pointing out that AdView **already** opens it's content in a WebView.

Comment: Ok I edit my question. I think there was a misunderstanding. What I meant is the content of the url sent by google which opened by clicking the view.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, not the way you want it to.

You would need to create an Activity that listens for

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

which would fire when all web intents were invoked.
And then the user would need to select that intent receiver instead of the existing browser.

You are attempting to fight the Android framework here.
Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Well lets just say it was a request. But I tried this as well, it is working but since I could not find a way to remove the chrome application to remove its action, my activity will not launch like when there's no other activity that listens action.View and chrome opening instantly. I heard that there's a way to inject an interface to a dark box class method that will trigger the interface every time the method invoked, that way I could invoke it every time startActivity is invoked, since the method invoked when the adMob view is clicked to open the ad.